# SQL Image Database assembling rows into HTML cells and rows

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a database of images which I want to output as a gallery ...

I want to display each image in its own cell `<td>image1</td>` and limit the number of cells to 7 per row.

```
<tr>
<td>image1</td><td>image2</td><td>image3</td><td>image4</td><td>image5</td><td>image6</td><td>image7</td>
</tr>
```

Then a new row would be created and continue to output all the images.

```
<tr>
<td>image8</td>
```

and so on ..

I know how to do a query, but I am lost as to how to assemble the rows into the format I am looking for.

Can anyone please help me it would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Are there any programmers available at your company that might be able help you? You will probably need a programmer to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple:

Query the database to get the desired information, loop through the results, construct a new row come each new loop.

```
       $sql = "Select * from table";
        mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

        if(mysql_num_rows !=0)
        {
    // Found at least one record, create table
        echo "<table>";
                echo "<tr>";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)
        {
$cell_count = 0;
    // Create a new row for each record found
        echo "<td>" . $row['image_column']. "</td>";
        $cell_count++;

if($cell_count == 7)
{
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
$cell_count = 0;
}
        }
    // Close the table
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>";
        }
```

Comment: this won't show 7 images per row...it will show 1 image per row.

Comment: That will just show all the images in 1 row.  So if there are 50 images, you'll have one long row with 50 cells.

Comment: Either I didn't notice the 7 per row, or it wasn't there in the first place. Sorry about that. However, updated once more.

Answer (score 0):

First run your query, then get the mysql_fetch_assoc in a variable. Then echo your beginning tags for the table and tr. Then create a foreach loop of the query assoc, as another variable such as row, and echo $row['image'] in a td. This will add a new td with the image for every entry in the database. Then echo your closing tags for the tr and table.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT image FROM table_name");
$query_a = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    echo "<table><tr>"
    foreach ($query_a as $row)) {
    echo "
    <td>" . $row['image'] . "</td>
    ";
    }
    echo "</tr></table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but try something like this

```
<table>
<?php
// make sure there is at least 1 row first
$cnt = 0;
$while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    if(++$cnt == 1) {
        echo '<tr>';
    } elseif($cnt % 7 == 0) {
        echo '</tr><tr>';
    }
    // show images in <td>'s
    echo "<td>" . $row['image']. "</td>";

}
echo '</tr>';
?>
</table>
```